# Add or subtract the first value of a column to the rest of the column (MATLAB)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I was wondering how to go about adding or subtracting the first value of my data to/from the rest of the column, so that the first row of data would be 0.

For instance, this:

```
A = [13.2   12.4   -11.7   6.3   -4.0
     14.2   13.1    -9.2   8.2   -4.1
     14.4   14.5    -7.6   10.0  -5.1];
```

Would change to:

```
0      0     0     0     0
1      0.7   2.5   1.9   0.1
1.2    2.1   4.1   3.7   1.1
```

I think I can check whether the first number is positive/negative by using sign() and choose whether to add or subtract this using an ifelse statement, but I am unsure how to apply this to each column individually (or if this is the best way!).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you made a sign mistake in your last column, or do you want the absolute value?

Comment: What you need is: `bsxfun(@minus,A,A(1,:))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the first row and subtract it from the matrix.

```
A = A - A(1, :)
```

Or for older versions of Matlab:

```
A = A - repmat(A(1, :), size(A, 1), 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually need element-by-element operation, as the definition of `bsxfun` states. In your case it should be:

```
A = [13.2   12.4   -11.7   6.3   -4.0
     14.2   13.1    -9.2   8.2   -4.1
     14.4   14.5    -7.6   10.0  -5.1];

B=bsxfun(@minus,A,A(1,:))
B =

         0         0         0         0         0
    1.0000    0.7000    2.5000    1.9000   -0.1000
    1.2000    2.1000    4.1000    3.7000   -1.1000
```

This is the result for your question description, but for the example that you add, I assume that you want the absolute values, so you need to add `abs`:

```
B=abs(bsxfun(@minus,A,A(1,:)))
B =

         0         0         0         0         0
    1.0000    0.7000    2.5000    1.9000   0.1000
    1.2000    2.1000    4.1000    3.7000   1.1000
```